# pyqt5, looping over QtWidgets

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have created a dialog with qtdesigner. I wanted to modify certain widgets (e.g. buttons) programmatically.
I have my pyuic generated gui.py and have created a guiLogic.py defining the class "myGui".

```
class myGui(QtWidgets.QDialog, inmoovServoGui.Ui_Dialog):
```

The class init calls then the "setupUi" function from the generated gui.py

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    QtWidgets.QDialog.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    self.setupUi(self)
    ...
```

In my python ide (pycharm) in the evaluate expression window I can type in now my class name followed by a . "myGui." and it will popup a list of all my QWidgets (beside others).

I have tried to get the same list but

```
myGui.__dict__.items()
```

does not contain the QWidgets. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are querying the class, when you should be querying the instance: `print(list(vars(self).items()))`.

Comment: OK, thanks, so I get all the widgets names and the widget object - great! I want to set sliders according to incoming data. I can find the slider now but how do I set the value of the slider? The list shows tupels of WidgetObjectName, <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QSlider object at ...> but the object does not show a "setValue" method?

Comment: Qt Docs: [QSlider](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qslider.html) -> [QAbstractSlider](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractslider.html).

Comment: @ekhumoro, thanks for your help. Found that I can use

    s = eval("self." + <sliderObjectName>)

to get a handle to the slider and then use s.setValue(<x>) to move the slider

Comment: @juerg no use `eval`, use getatter: `s = getattr(self,  <sliderObjectName>)`

Comment: @eyllanesc, thanks, updated my code